# On a set $S$ with exactly one element $x$ define $x+x=x$ and  $x\cdot x=x.$ Prove that $\{x\}$ is a ring.

Tags: ring-theory

I am trying to prove that axioms A1, A2, A3, A4, M2, D hold.

so A1 :

$$ a+b=b+a$$
$$x+x+x+x=x+x+x+x$$
$$4x=4x$$
Am I on the right way?

Comment: I don't think you are. I understand that your Axiom 1 says that if you take two elements $a$ and $b$ then $a+b=b+a.$ You have only one element in this set, that is $x$. So you have to take $a=x$ and $b=x$. We have $a+b=x+x=x=x+x=b+a.$

Comment: What does $x+x+x+x=x+x+x+x$ have to do with anything?

Comment: @Chris: Best guess: the OP is reckoning that the only element is $x+x$ and substituting that for both $a$ and $b$ in the statement of commutativity.

Comment: Name your element $x$ by $0$ and everything will make more sense.

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by A1, etc. These are labels in your texbook, not universally accepted labels.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not. In order to show that $$a+b=b+a\tag{1}$$ for all elements $a,b\in S$, you merely have to observe that since $x$ is the **only** element of $S$, the only thing that you can substitute for $a$ and $b$ in $(1)$ is $x$. When you do that, you get $x+x=x+x$; is that true? Yes, because both sides are equal to $x$ by the definition of $+$.

I’ll do one other example as an illustration. I don’t know for sure, but I suspect that your D is $$a\cdot(b+c)=(a\cdot b)+(a\cdot c)\tag{2}$$ for all $a,b,c\in S$. Again, the only thing in $S$ is $x$, so the only possible instance of $(2)$ to be checked is $x\cdot(x+x)=(x\cdot x)+(x\cdot x)$; is it true? On the lefthand side we have $$x\cdot(x+x)=x\cdot x=x\;,$$ and on the righthand side we have $$(x\cdot x)+(x\cdot x)=x+x=x\;;$$ these are indeed equal, so $(2)$ is true for all possible choices of $a,b$, and $c$.

One last comment: $4x$ makes no sense here. We have not defined any operation that combines natural numbers and this object $x$.

Comment: $4x$ is always defined for a ring, $4x = x + x + x + x$ by definition.

Comment: @David: As a notational convention, yes. But given the overall confusion, I think it important to be clear about what is really going on, which is *not* the multiplication that it might naïvely be taken as.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ The definitions simply [transport the ring structure](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%20transport%20structure) from the subring $\:\{0\}\subset \mathbb Z\:$ to $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the required properties of a ring are immediate for the [trivial ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_ring), since any expressions on the left- or right-hand side evaluate to $x$, the unique element.

That leaves the existence of a additive identity and inverse, met by $x+x = x$ and a multiplicative identity, met by $x \cdot x = x$.